# How to remove synchronized LOG file in postgresql replication?

Tags: postgresql, replication, database-replication, postgresql-9.2

while implementing replication, log files of 16mb are frequently created in C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\data\pg_xlog directory during transaction in the Master(Primary) system. How to automatically delete the synchronized log files.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you want to use that space for something else then your server might crash if - for example - you create enough changes in your db that it will crate enough WAL to take back all this space you freed. If you need more space then reduce number of WAL segments created thru one of those parameters:  `(2 + checkpoint_completion_target) * checkpoint_segments + 1 or checkpoint_segments + wal_keep_segments + 1 files`

Comment: After applying the replication on the standby(secondary) system. How can I delete the synchronized log files of 16mb. Actually I am getting 1TB of log files per day.

Comment: WALs on your master will get deleted/recycled regardless of what was replicated to slave(s). If you are exceeding number of files set by those parameters I have mentioned then you likely have WAL archiving turned on and it keeps failing, preventing system from removing files. See if you have enabled `show archive_mode`.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński can you please specify where can i set above mentioned parameters?

Comment: They are in postgresql.conf, so on Windows this file could be in `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\data`, on Linux possibly in: `/etc/postgresql/9.2/main`

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński  Actually,i have confusion on where would i set the parameter mentioned above  in postgresql.conf file.

Comment: I have them commented out in my config files, but those are from 9.6 and not all of those parameters are still present in more recent Postgres version. `archive_mode` should be in both, but if it isn't, then just add it wherever in said file. AFAIK there are no "sections" or order in there.